# Excel VBA: Range Compare, For Each Loops, Nested IF Statements

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, foreach, range

Looking for assistance with the following:

Goal:

1. Compare cells in 2 defined ranges (same size) one by one. If they are the same then move on to the next set of cells. If not:
2. Input an integer (between 1 to 2000) in a corresponding cell within a 3rd range (same size as the other 2). Run this in a For loop until the cells in the first 2 ranges equal each other.
3. Once achieved, then move on to the next set of cells and so forth.

The code I've written up so far is outlined below but its not producing the right results. From what I can tell, the hCell value loops while the rest don't which is putting the If comparison conditions off...

Thank you for any help with this!

```
Sub Update()
    
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    
    Sheets("Funds").Select
    
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    
    'resets the "looping cells" from NR8 to PF207.
    'Dim d As Integer
        
        For d = 8 To 207
            Range(Cells(d, 382), Cells(d, 422)) = ""
        Next
    
    Dim e As Integer
    e = 1
        
    Dim fRng As Range: Set fRng = Range("RB8:SP207")
    Dim fCell As Range
    
    Dim gRng As Range: Set gRng = Range("SU8:UI207")
    Dim gCell As Range
    
    Dim hRng As Range: Set hRng = Range("NR8:PF207")
    Dim hCell As Range
    
    Dim i As Integer
    i = i
        
        
    For e = 8 To 207
        For Each fCell In fRng.Cells
            For Each gCell In gRng.Cells
                For Each hCell In hRng.Cells
    
        If Cells(e, 191).Value = 0 Then
           Exit For
        
        Else
      
                    If (fCell.Value >= gCell.Value Or gCell.Value = "N/A") Then
                        Exit For
                
                    Else
                        For i = 0 To 2000
                        
                            If fCell.Value >= gCell.Value Then
                                Exit For
                            Else
                                hCell.Value = i
                                If fCell.Value >= gCell.Value Then
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next i
                    End If
                End If
                Next hCell, gCell, fCell
             End If
           Next e
    
    
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the values in the first two ranges are in some way dependent on the values in the third.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Update()

    Const NCOLS = 41 ' 41
    Const NROWS = 200 ' 200
    Const LOOPMAX = 2000 ' 2000

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
    Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Integer, t0 As Double
    t0 = Timer
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("RB8")
    Set rng2 = ws.Range("SU8")
    Set rng3 = ws.Range("NR8")

    'resets NR8 to PF207.
    rng3.Resize(NROWS, NCOLS).Value = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 1 To NROWS
        Application.StatusBar = "Row " & r & " of " & NROWS
        For c = 1 To NCOLS
           Set cell1 = rng1.Offset(r - 1, c - 1)
           Set cell2 = rng2.Offset(r - 1, c - 1)
           If (cell1.Value <> cell2.Value) Or (cell2.Value = "N/A") Then
               i = 0
               Do
                   rng3.Offset(r - 1, c - 1) = i
                   i = i + 1
               Loop Until cell1.Value = cell2.Value Or i > LOOPMAX
           End If
        Next c
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation, Int(Timer - t0) & " seconds"
    rng3.Select
End Sub
```